# Basic auth with Alamofire does not work

Tags: swift, http-headers, alamofire, basic-authentication

I have been trying to use Alamofire's basic authentication support:

```
self.sessionManager.request(request)
    .authenticate(user: user, 
                  password: passwordHashAsHex)
```

However, I get a 403 from my webserver.

If I add the auth header my self:

```
let authString = "\(user):\(passwordHashAsHex)"

guard let auth = authString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        throw ...
}

request.setValue("Basic \(auth.base64EncodedString())",
    forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization"
)
```

It works just fine.

Checking `response.request!.allHTTPHeaderFields` in Alamofire's completion/response handler, I note that there is no entry `Authorization`. Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon careful reading of [the documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#authentication) we find:

> The authenticate method on a `Request` will automatically provide a `URLCredential` to a `URLAuthenticationChallenge` when appropriate.
>
> ...
>
> Depending upon your server implementation, an `Authorization` header may also be appropriate.

It seems that my server only accepts the latter variant, so I indeed *have* to add the header manually. `Request.authorizationHeader` can take care of the grunt work.